# Can we execute JUnit 5 and TestNG tests in the same project using maven-surefire-plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, testng, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am writing unit tests for a project which already has a few TestNG tests. Since I am using JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) to write new tests, I observed the problem that **only TestNG** tests are run when i do "mvn clean verify"

Below are my dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And since surefire plugin from `2.22.0` onwards provides JUnit 5 support below is my plugin section for surefire

```
           <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
           </plugin>
```

Is there any way I can keep both in the project and be able to run all tests through maven ? This is necesary so that code coverage report shows all tests together.

Also I noted that all tests(JUnit + TestNG) run together through maven if I use JUNIT 4 tests with the help of vintage-engine dependency. I am confused why this does not happen with JUnit 5.

Comment: As per documentation https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html "TestNG 6.5.1 and higher provides support to run TestNG and JUnit 4.x in current Maven project" . Junit 5 is not supported

Answer (score 3):

It's supported in a "preview feature" style.

- (1) Have the [TestNGine](https://github.com/testng-team/testng-junit5) in your test runtime dependencies.
- (2) Help (force) Surefire to use the JUnit Platform provider

See this simple integration test [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/testng-team/testng-junit5/blob/master/src/it/basic/pom.xml) for a possible setup:

```xml
  <dependencies>

    <dependency> <!-- (1) -->
      <groupId>com.github.testng-team</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency> <!-- (2) -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/junit-team/testng-engine as well.